# Max from MySQL query from one part of array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array from a MySQL query that has two parts to it, I want to get the max from just the first part, but when I do `max($row)` it returns the max of a date because those values are higher. When I try `max(array_column($row, 'SUM(DISTRIBUTED_AMOUNT / EXCHANGE_RATE)'));` I get this error `max(): Array must contain at least one element` Is there a way to do it only based on the first part?

```
Array
(
    [SUM(DISTRIBUTED_AMOUNT / EXCHANGE_RATE)] => 19.1630000055071
    [DATE] => 2013-11
)
```

Comment: Is this a multidimensional array, and you want the sub-array with the greatest value for `SUM(DISTRIBUTED_AMOUNT / EXCHANGE_RATE)`? [This answer is probably what you're after](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17339754/541091)

Comment: If it is multidimensional, post a little more of the array for context, and clarify what your output should be -whether the entire sub-array, or just the single value like `19.1630000055071`. If you have PHP 5.5, it can be easily done with `max(array_column())`

Comment: It is a multi dimensional array, array_column looks like the right thing so I tried this `max(array_column($row, 'SUM(DISTRIBUTED_AMOUNT / EXCHANGE_RATE)'));` but I get this error `max(): Array must contain at least one element`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use foreach while keeping track of the attribute you want. Take Date for example. Keep a variable MaxDate = FirstRow[Date]. Then Iterate through all of them and check if the actual row is higher than the actual MaxDate. This is a brute-force way, but it will surely work. You can also use SQL to actually take the max.

```
SELECT MAX(something) FROM 
       SELECT SUM(DISTRIBUTED_AMOUNT / EXCHANGE_RATE) AS something
       FROM whatever;
```

PHP Brute-force:

```
$max = $result[0]['SUM(DISTRIBUTED_AMOUNT / EXCHANGE_RATE)'];
foreach($result as $row){
    if($row['SUM(DISTRIBUTED_AMOUNT / EXCHANGE_RATE)'] > $max)
         max = $row['SUM(DISTRIBUTED_AMOUNT / EXCHANGE_RATE)'];
}

echo $max;
```

Note that you have to use all rows in the result. Remember to check whether or not there are elements in the query result.

Comment: You can't have two aggregates in the same expression. You need to use a subquery -- the inner query does `SUM() AS whatever`, the outer query does `MAX(whatever)`.

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry. Nested selects should be used.

Comment: I need to do it with my existing array as I am trying to do it off an already existing query without doing another query.

Comment: Then just use the brute-force metgod I mentioned. That should work just fine. EDIT: Added PHP brute-force. Check if it helps

Comment: I get this error when using the brute-force method `Illegal string offset 'SUM(DISTRIBUTED_AMOUNT / EXCHANGE_RATE)'`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php try that