# How to get max time form array elements

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get highest time from `time_array`.In below code I manually gave timings it is wrong.

`time_array` is like this,

```
    Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [1] => Array ( [date] => 2016-04-09 [time] => 0900 [after_time] => 1100 
            [2] => Array ( [date] => 2016-04-10 [time] => 1100 [after_time] => 1300 
            [3] => Array ( [date] => 2016-04-11 [time] => 1300 [after_time] => 1500 
        )
    )
```

my code,

```
    <?php
        foreach ($time_array AS $row) {
          for($j=$start; $j < $limit ; $j++){
            if($row[$start]['time']=='1300' && $row[$start]['after_time']=='1500' ){
            //code
            }else{
            //code
            }
         }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Is it `max(time)`?

Comment: what is `after_time` ?

Comment: Is the actual time calculated from `time` and `after_time`? Or are you just looking for the highest value for the `time` of each item?

Comment: A `}` and `)` is missing from code...and a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339421/find-highest-value-in-multidimensional-array  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using foreach 
check this once

```
foreach ($time_array  as $arr){
    $ar = array_column($arr, 'time');
}
echo max($ar);
```