# How to Get Max value fetching between results?

Tags: php, fetching-strategy

How to Get Max value fetching between results?

As an example 
i want to get max "C" value from results "1-3".

```
success:    true
message:    ""
result: 
0:  
C:  333

1:  
C:  332

2:  
C:  331.85

3:
C:  331.5

4:
C:  333.75249964

5:  
C:  333.68499948
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you try to follow this 
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43345764) ?

```
$max= max(array_column($result, 'C'));
```

If you use native PHP functions you get performance improvement.