# find the greatest key value and return other keys and its corresponding values from multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array with the following format. Am trying to print that array which have the greatest radius. A function that should return the details with greatest radius. Here for example for Davis it should return the 2nd inner array with radius 106(which have the maximum radius) and for john it should return 0th array with radius 50.

i tried with the solution provided in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339421/find-highest-value-in-multidimensional-array).

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => davis
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [xaxis] => 445
                            [yaxis] => 447
                            [radius] => 80

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [xaxis] => 468
                            [yaxis] => 447
                            [radius] => 77

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [xaxis] => 409
                            [yaxis] => 199
                            [radius] => 106

                        )

                )

        )
       [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => john
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [xaxis] => 311
                            [yaxis] => 383
                            [radius] => 50

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [xaxis] => 527
                            [yaxis] => 310
                            [radius] => 21

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [xaxis] => 465
                            [yaxis] => 431
                            [radius] => 48

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [xaxis] => 339
                            [yaxis] => 326
                            [radius] => 43

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: So., you've tried the solution and what happened?

Comment: According to provided link in your case it is: `echo max(array_column($arr[0]['data'], 'radius'));`

Comment: @u_mulder Is it crime to answer to OP's question if no effort provided?

Comment: yes. but it return the highest radius only. not the xaxis and yaxis values for corresponding radius

Comment: @DrakulaPredator not a crime, it's your choice only)

Comment: Then iterate ovevr your `data` and store all keys from current greatest value. After loop - return stored data.

Comment: Have you tried sorting inner arrays and print `$arr[i][data][0]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snippet, I am considering radius is unique or else it will overlap

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    // it will map radius as key and whole array as its value
    $temp = array_column($value['data'], null, 'radius');
    // I am fetching max key by which I will fetch data in next step
    $key = max(array_keys($temp));
    // fetching data of max value and saving it for the name
    $result[$value['name']] = $temp[$key];
}
print_r($result);die;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/2q5FH).

If you want to maintain your array structure as it is then,

```
$result = [];
$i      = 0;
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $temp               = array_column($value['data'], null, 'radius');
    $key                = max(array_keys($temp));
    $result[$i]['name'] = $value['name'];
    $result[$i]['data'] = $temp[$key];
    $i++;
}
print_r($result);die;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/WTZtu).