# Manipulate values of a two-dimensional array and find the highest value using only for loop

Tags: php

How can I find the highest value in the sales key, for this case will be 21, using only "for loop"?

I have been trying to get the values for the sales index in order to find which sale had the highest value, however everything I do, its just simply to run all the array elements and show them into the screen.

```
$Vehicles = [
    "v1" => [
        "name" => "Audi",
        "model" => "2019",
        "sales" => 21
    ],
    "v2" => [
        "name" => "BMW",
        "model" => "2019",
        "sales" => 8
    ],
    "v3" => [
        "name" => "Aston Martin",
        "model" => "2019",
        "sales" => 7
    ]
];
```

The highest selling is 21.
key = "sales"
value = 21

Comment: Please post one of your attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/how-to-sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: since its an associative array, get the keys first, then use `for`

Comment: and why on earth is it a requirement to just only use `for` loop, whats why there's a `foreach`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find highest value in multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339421/find-highest-value-in-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

Since PHP 5.5 there is array_column

> `array_column(array,column_key);`

So, in your case to get max value -

`$Highest_Selling_Value = max(array_column($Vehicles, 'sales'));`

Comment: Yes, this is an easy answer, the problem is that it must be solved with pure for loop, it is an algorithm exercise. The reason is because I need to create a method inside a class and then  pass a multidimensional array as a parameter and then find the highest value of an specific key value.

Comment: if it works for you mark as the answer and upvote .@ChristianHernandez

Answer (score 0):

use array_column

```
max(array_column($Vehicles, 'sales'));
```