# How to get array which has an the highest value in the array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Name1
        [Totaal] => 13
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Name2
        [Totaal] => 117
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Name3
        [Totaal] => 39
    )
)
```

Now i would like to get the the array with the highest "Totaal"
In this example, i would like to have returned:

```
Array
    (
        [Name] => Name2
        [Totaal] => 117
    )
```

I have found methods like:

```
max(array_column($arr, 'Totaal'));
```

But this only returns the max value, and not the array itself. Any ideas?

Comment: That looks very much like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339421/find-highest-value-in-multidimensional-array.  The answer you've shown may not get what you want but do any of the others solve your problem?

Comment: I know, i have taken the array from that question. The question itself is different though. I'll edit the array to not cause any confusion

Comment: Don't know about the code. But I think it's possible to sort the arrays on the Total entry so the highest value goes first. After that just only return the first entry

Comment: There are great solutions to this in that duplicate, for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/17339531/476.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
$array = [
    [
        'key' => 'key1',
        'value' => 13,
    ],
    [
        'key' => 'key2',
        'value' => 117,
    ],
    [
        'key' => 'key3',
        'value' => 39

    ]
];

$result = array_reduce(
    $array,
    fn(array $carry, array $item) => $carry === null || $item['value'] > $carry['value'] ? $item : $carry,
    null
);

var_dump($result);

// array(2) {
//  ["key"]=>
//  string(4) "key2"
//  ["value"]=>
//  int(117)
// }
```

Comment: this only from php 7.4