# Getting only the highest value

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, php-7

I have this foreach loop and I want only take and display the array of the largest value of `buildings`

this is my loop

```
$this->TaTarVillages = array();
foreach ($this->GetTaTaRVillages() as $value) {
    $this->TaTarVillages[] = array(
        'id' => $value['id'],
        'player_id' => $value['player_id'],
        'player_name' => $value['player_name'],
        'village_name' => $value['village_name'],
        'alliance_id' => $value['alliance_id'],
        'alliance_name' => $value['alliance_name'],
        'buildings' => $this->getWonderLandLevel($value['buildings'])
    );
}
```

Using PHP 7

Comment: you might want to tag this question with the language you are using

Comment: I am using php7 as a programming language

Comment: What if there is a tie for highest? Only keep the first? Do you want to potentially keep all rows with the highest value?  Barmar's approach is found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17339754/2943403).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an array if you only want the largest one. Each time through the loop, check if the current value is larger than the largest one you've gotten so far, and replace it if so.

```
$largestVillage = $this->GetTaTaRVillages();
$largestVillage['buildings'] = $this->getWonderLandLevel($largestVillage['buildings']);
foreach ($this->GetTaTaRVillages() as $value) {
    $buildings = $this->getWonderLandLevel($value['buildings']);
    if ($buildings > $largestVillage['buildings']) {
        $largestVillage = $value;
        $largestVillage['buildings'] = $huildings;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the correct result but I have errors
`Notice: Undefined index: buildings in AuthController.php on line 52`
`Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in AuthController.php on line 291`

getWonderLandLevel function

`function getWonderLandLevel($builds) {
$b_arr = explode(',', $builds);
$indx = 0;
foreach ($b_arr as $b_str) {
++$indx;
$b2 = explode(' ', $b_str);             $itemId = $b2[0];             $level = $b2[1];             if ($itemId == 40) {                 return $level;             }         }         return 0;     }`

Comment: I'm calling `getWonderLandLevel()` the same way your original code does. I assume that's correct.

Comment: right it's worked without any errors, thank you :)