# Get value of another key of corresponding highest value in PHP

Tags: php

I want to get 'name' of highest value in 'amount' in the array.
The code is given below:

```
$data = [
    ['id' => 0, 'name' => 'Test', 'amount' => 3,],
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Test', 'amount' => 2,],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Test', 'amount' => 1,],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Test', 'amount' => 0,],
    ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'High', 'amount' => 6,],
    ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'Test', 'amount' => 4,],
    ['id' => 6, 'name' => 'Test', 'amount' => 5,],
];
```

Comment: What have you researched and tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate and compare which is larger and keep the largest.

```
$max = PHP_INT_MIN;
$largest = [];
foreach($data as $item) {
    if($item['amount'] > $max) {
        $max = $item['amount'];
        $largest = $item;
    }
}

echo $largest['name'];
```

prints

```
High
```

Of course you can use name directly, but I think you want to keep track of the array with the highest amount.

Comment: Theoretically, the amount values could all be negative. Then the solution can fail. Better is to set $max = PHP_INT_MIN;.

Comment: [From 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17339754/2943403)

Comment: Sorting the entire array will not be as efficient as Markus's answer.  The other two answers are working too hard.

Comment: Sorting the array (without making a copy before) will mutate the original data. That often is unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
usort($data, fn(array $a, array $b): int => $b['amount'] <=> $a['amount']);
$highestAmountItem = reset($data);
$highestName = $highestAmountItem['name'];
```

We're sorting `$data` array items by their amounts (using [spaceship operator <=>](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/combined-comparison-operator)). Then the highest element is the first one, and we can retrieve it via `reset` function.

Answer (score -1):

The solution to sort the entire array in descending order of 'amount' offers more flexibility.

```
array_multisort( array_column($data,'amount'),SORT_DESC,$data);
```

After that, with the index 0, I have access to the entire line with the highest 'amount'.

```
var_dump($data[0]);
//array(3) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["name"]=> string(4) "High" ["amount"]=> int(6) }

var_dump($data[0]['name']);
//string(4) "High"
```